# Работа с датой в C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Верный ли подход, или можно выполнить работу с датой проще. В частности, необходимо выполнить выборку выборку полей из базы данных, значение даты у которых находится между началом и концом текущего дня, т.е от 00:00:00 до 00:00:00 нового дня. Так как планируется использование в разных временных зонах, использую UTC.

Вот так объявляю диапазон выборки

```
var startOfDay = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, 0, 0, 0);
var endOfDay = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Затем, делаю запрос к БД, где проверяю принадлежит ли дата у записи указанному диапазону. В БД дата хранится в формате UTC.

Comment: Все зависит от контекста. Возможно проще написать хранимку (со всей логикой) и просто дергать ее из C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, неверный.

1. Дата может измениться между обращениями к `DateTime.UtcNow`, поэтому ты можешь получить неверную дату (с ошибкой на день, месяц или год).
2. Всё же проще:

   ```
   var startOfDay = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
   var endOfDay = startOfDay.AddDays(1);
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, этот код неправильно работает в последний день месяца: вы меняете день, но не месяц.

Во-вторых, можно проще:

```
var startOfDay = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var endOfDay = startOfDay.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: О, мы почти одинаково ответили, только ты другой баг нашёл :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага, причём исправили оба :)

Comment: И кого мне из вас двоих правильным отметить?:)))

Comment: @QuaternioNoir, кто нашёл более интересный баг?)

Comment: @QuaternioNoir: В крайнем случае бросьте монетку :)